# Django order_by hstore DictionaryField key

Tags: django, postgresql, django-models, django-orm, django-hstore

I would like to order a queryset based on a key in a DictionaryField I have using hstore. I currently have the following:

```
objects = MyModel.objects.filter(**items).filter(
                is_private=False).order_by('dict_field')
```

the contents of the field are the following:

```
{'1': '100', '2': '150', ..., 'some_key': 'some_value'}
```

and I would like to sort solely based off the `'1'` key. The way I have it right now seems to order the results in an ascending order but with the zero values on top.